# MIPS instruction and machine code

Tags: assembly, mips

A register `$t0` contains value `0x10008040`. Write out the machine code for
the MIPS instruction that loads a word from the main memory at address
`0x10008048`, and stores the result in register `$s1`. The instruction should make use of register `$t0`. Answer as a hexadecimal value for the machine code.

i have come so far in this question

```
 lw $t0, 8($s1)
```

then i am stack how to do thanks for help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually you have only found the instruction, so it's not ending there from your spec.

**Write out the machine code for the MIPS instruction**.

```
lw $s1, 8($t0)
```

In order to write the machine code for this instruction you need to look at MIPS reference sheet [MIPS Reference sheet](https://www.kth.se/social/files/54948c82f276540590491ed4/mips-ref-cheat-sheet.pdf)

If you look at the sheet the `lw` has *opcode* 35 and for `$1` is 17 , for `$t0` is 8 and offset is 8. Arrange it as following

```
op  rs rt  immidiate
35  8  17  8
```

To binary

```
100011  01000  10001  0000000000001000
```

Group as 4 bits

```
1000 1101  0001 0001 0000 0000 0000 1000
```

To hexadecimal

```
0x8D110008
```

**Answer as a hexadecimal value for the machine code**.

```
0x8D110008
```

Answer (score 3):

Almost got it, but you need to swap the registers. I think that's it, just one instruction.

```
lw $s1, 8($t0) // $s1 = *($t0 + 8)
```